# Creating new commit from older commit using jgit?

Tags: java, git, github, gitlab, jgit

I want to restore a file to a given commit in the same master branch. I have created temporary branch changes for this, but still no success. I only want changes from the old commit id. I don't want to merge current and old commit changes, only old commit changes and then commit this as new commit.

```
Repository repository = new FileRepository("E:" + "/.git");
Git gitObj = new Git(repository);

// create changes branch
Ref changes = gitObj.branchCreate().setName("changes").call();
System.out.println("result of branch create " + changes);

// checkout branch changes
Ref checkout = gitObj.checkout().setName("changes").call();
System.out.println("result of checkout " + checkout);

// apply that specific commit to this branch
CherryPickCommand cherryPickCommand = gitObj.cherryPick();
cherryPickCommand.include(getAnyObjectIdFromRevision(2));
cherryPickCommand.setStrategy(MergeStrategy.OURS);
cherryPickCommand.call();

// switch back to master branch
checkout = gitObj.checkout().setName("master").call();
System.out.println("master checkout result " + checkout);

//retrive the object id of the latest commit on branch
ObjectId mergeBase = repository.resolve("changes");

//actual merge
MergeResult merge = gitObj.merge().include(mergeBase).setMessage("merged changes").call();


System.out.println("Merge-Results for id: " + mergeBase + ": " + merge);
for (Map.Entry<String,int[][]> entry : merge.getConflicts().entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Key: " + entry.getKey());
    for(int[] arr : entry.getValue()) {
        System.out.println("value: " + Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}   

// delete branch
DeleteBranchCommand deleteBranchCommand = gitObj.branchDelete();
deleteBranchCommand.setBranchNames("changes");
deleteBranchCommand.setForce(true);
```